# Bulk uploading data to Parse.com

Tags: json, import, parse-platform, dataset

I have about 10GB worth of data that I would like to import to Parse. the data is currently in JSON format which is great for importing data using the [parse importer](https://parse.com/docs/data#data-import).

However I have no unique identifier to these objects. Of course they have unique properties e.g. a url, the ids pointing to specific objects need to be constant.

What would be the best way to edit the large amount of data -in bulk- on their server without running into request issues (as I'm currently on the free pricing model) and without taking too much time to alter the data.

#### Option 1

Import the data once and export the data in JSON with the newly assigned objectIds. Then edit them locally matching the url then replace the class with the new edited data. Any new editions will receive a new objectId by Parse.

How much downtime between import and export will there be as I would need to delete the class and recreate it? Are there any other concerns with this methodology?

#### Option 2

Query for the URL or array of URLs and then edit the data then re-save. This means the data will persist indefinitely but as the edit will consist of hundreds of thousands of objects will this most likely over run the request limit?

#### Option 3

Is there a better option I am missing?

Comment: Can you add a unique ID to your data before importing?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you an use any old unique identifier as long as it is unique. So I imagine it won't be too difficult to code up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best option is to upload to Parse then edit through their normal channels. Using various hacks it is possible to stay below the 30pings/second offered as part of the free tier. You can iterate over the data using [background jobs](http://blog.parse.com/2013/09/04/introducing-background-jobs/) (written in Javascript) -- you may need to slow down your processing so you don't hit limits. The super hacky way is to download from the table to a client (iOS/Android) app and then push back up to Parse. If you do this in batch (**not** a synchronous for loop, by the way), then the latency alone will keep you under the 30ping/sec limit.

I'm not sure why you're worried about downtime. If the data isn't already uploaded to Parse, can't you upload it, pull it down and edit it, and re-upload it -- taking as long as you'd like? Do this in a separate table from any you are using in production, and you should be just fine.

Comment: In response to "can't you upload it, pull it down and edit it, and re-upload it -- taking as long as you'd like?" The problem with that is that you can't reupload to an existing class - which means for a set time that class will not exist. Therefore you have to delete the class in order to achieve that. I guess then you'd have to switch between two classes one representing the old data, and one with the new data-to-be uploaded :(

Comment: you can absolutely re-upload to an existing class. i've done it many times